# Centering table data under right-aligned tabularx header

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment

I'm trying to align the following table so that the "21" is centered under its header.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{1.09\textwidth}{|cll>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
\textbf{ID}     & \textbf{Severity}     & \textbf{Vulnerability}       &
\textbf{Occurrences} \\
\hline
111111         & Lorem                 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & 21 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{example}
\label{table:example}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I can use `\centering` instead of `\raggedleft` for the last column to center the numbers under the header but then the header ends up too much to the left, I want the header to be like in the above picture.

[image]

Is there anyway I can get the combination of these two? The header aligned to the right like in the first picture but the number centered under the header like in the second picture.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Have you any reason for a tabularx which flows into the margins?

Comment: @Bernard The reason i'm using tabularx is to get the same width as my widest table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `X` type colum for the 3rd instead of the 4th cell: `\begin{tabularx}{1.09\textwidth}{|clXc|}`. With `\makecell[r]{\textbf{Occurrences}}` you can then right align the header:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{1.09\textwidth}{|clXc|}
\hline
\textbf{ID}     & \textbf{Severity}     & \textbf{Vulnerability}       &
\makecell[r]{\textbf{Occurrences}} \\
\hline
111111         & Lorem                 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & 21 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{example}
\label{table:example}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe using `\thead` for all  column heads would simplify the code?

Comment: Thank you, that was an easy solution that gives the right look!